# not able to install mysql-server on docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, microservices, seneca

I am using microservices for seneca with docker. Now when I am trying to create an image with Dockerfile and trying installing mysql-server then it gets hang and if I manually try to install mysql-server inside docker container its gets installed by service mysql start fails everytime. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use a the [standard mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)?

Comment: Check @CristianBaldi's comment. If you really want to create it by yourself you have to provide the dockerfile you wrote so we can check. I would guess you need to perform an apt-get update before?